# Excel Lookup Formula with Two Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

Sorry about the heading but im finding it hard to explain so ill give it my best shot.

Here is my problem 
I have 3 cells: Lender, product and productID I have a vlookup that fills the lender and product cells just fine
However i want a way to bring back the productID back from another worksheet matching with lender and product.

For instance if call1 = newcastle and cell2 = 2 year fixed then cell3 = 422
[image]

I tried using a vlookup but doesnt seem to work, Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to do this with VBA or a formula?

Comment: if possible in a formula as iv never used vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to using combination of the MATCH and INDEX functions that some may find more straightforward is to first insert a column on your lookup table and concatenate the cobmination of columns you wish to search by.

=CONCATENATE(B8,C8)

Then you can still use the Vlookup function, but instead of only entering the one column to lookup on, you would combined them in the lookup so that the combination of them looks up to the combination of them on the lookup table.

=VLOOKUP(B3&C3,A9:D10,4,0)

Comment: I ended up going with this option and it works perfect thanks. With my lack of skills this was the only one i managed to get working.

Comment: My final code was =CONCATENATE(AA2," "&" ",AC2) then to find product id i used a vlookup =VLOOKUP(AD2,DATA[[#All],[Column1]:[PK_ProductID]],2,FALSE)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Index` and `Match` to perform a lookup with two criteria. Here is an example of one from  http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MATCH(1,(A13=$B$2:$B$10)*(B13=$C$2:$C$10),0))
```

As mentioned on the site, it is an array formula so rather than just pressing enter when you use the formula, you need to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To break down how the formula is formatted:

```
=INDEX(a,MATCH(1,(b=c)*(d=e),0))
```

- a = The whole range with all the data in it
- b = The first criteria for the data to be filtered on
- c = The range in which the first criteria needs to be searched
- d = The second criteria for the data to be filtered on
- e = The range in which the second criteria needs to be searched

Make sure that you use `$` in the correct places as in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that *Newcastle* is in A2 and *2 year fixed* is in B2. It doesn't matter what worksheet they are on.In another worksheet named *Data* you have a table with a column of lenders in column X, products in column Y and product IDs in column Z. There are column labels in row 1 so the real data starts in row 2 and there are 2587 rows of data. In the first worksheet's C2 where you want the double lookup for a *ProductID* that matches *Lende* and *Product* try this formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Data'!$Z$2:$Z$9999, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$9998)+(('Data'!$X$2:$X$9999<>$A2)+('Data'!$Y$2:$Y$9999<>$B2))*1E99,,))), "no match")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeep i tried this but for some reason it diddnt work and i think in the process i confused myself. Thanks for helping though

Comment: @RustyHamster - The most common error people make when transcribing that style of formula is changing the relative reference between ROW(1:9998) and Z2:Z9999. ROW(1:9998) is not referring to the actual row on the worksheet. It is referring to the *position within* Z2:Z9999. If it was Z50:Z95 (with X50:X95 and Y50:Y95) then it would be ROW(1:46) because there are 46 possible cells within Z50:Z95.